# Visual Studio project Code Analyser path has changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I created a default asp.net core 3.1 project. When I unload the project and reload, the three analyzers in `Dependencies` > `Analyzers` have yellow exclamation marks and they become absolute filepaths e.g.

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Web\analyzers\cs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Analyzers.dll`

They also don't have properties (which is where that filepath normally lies)

**What happened here? How can I fix this?**

After unloading and reloading project:

[image: Erroneous Full File Path]

*Clicking on the above analyzers shows nothing in the properties window*

What it normally looks like:

[image: Normal]

*These defaulted analyzers show a populated path property*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the default project is created without Nuget packages, I managed to fix this by installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Analyzers 3.1.0` with the NuGet package manager.

After unloading and reloading again, it worked.